# Empty set and cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is it correct to write that the set E = { {{∅}} , {∅}} has cardinality of 2, but the empty set is not an element of the set?

Comment: yes, that would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. $E$ has two elements, and they are $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ and $\{\emptyset\}$. Neither of those is $\emptyset$, so $\emptyset \notin E$.