# Cardinality of Edge set of Empty, null and trivial graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

What will be the size of graph of **Empty graph**, **null graph** and **trivial graph**? In all of these cases there is no edges, so Cardinality of Edge is zero for all, Right?

I also read this question: [Empty set and cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510542/empty-set-and-cardinality)
But still I got question for edge set E ={} for all three types of graph written above.

Thank you.

Comment: A good real life application for a graph with no edges: If no-one can communicate with anyone, you'd really better know about that and fix it ASAP.

Comment: @LeeMosher thank you for helping me to fix this.

Comment: Define those three graphs.

Comment: What William said. The definition of empty, null and trivial graph changes from book to book.

Comment: yes, it differs from book to book. I will write definition what i read recently. **Empty graph** have some vertex set V but its edge set is empty set. Sometimes empty space is also called as empty graph. It depends on author. **Trivial graph** is empty graph with one vertex. And **Null graph** is a graph with no vertices and no edges. Null graph can also be called as empty graph.